# How to launch a file protocol URL with an anchor from Java?

Tags: java, file, uri, anchor, file-uri

From a Java program, I need to launch the default browser on a local HTML file, pointed to an anchor inside the file.  In Java SE 6, the java.awt.Desktop.browse method will open the file, but will not honor the anchor, so something like the following opens the file at the top, but does not page the browser to the anchor:

```
Desktop.getDesktop("file:///C:/foo/bar.html#anchor");
```

Sun says here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6477862 that anchors are not supported in the file URI protocol.

Does anyone have a better answer?

I can use Java SE 6.  I would be OK with a Windows only solution.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this another way, because no amount of quoting or spaces in any of these examples worked for me.

1  Detect if the file URI has a anchor or query string

2  If so, create a temp file `File tmpfile = File.createTempFile("apphelp", ".html")` with a meta-redirect to the actual file URI I desire:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=help.html#set_filter" />
</head></html>
```

3  Execute the local rundll command using new temporary URI:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
  "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler \"" 
  +tmpfile.toURI().toString()+ "\"");
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: This also works with `Desktop.browse()` - at least on Windows

Comment: Works on Linux too (Linux Mint at least) but via `Desktop.getDesktop().open(htmlFile);`

Answer (score 1):

Solution on Windows is:

rundll32 URL.dll, FileProtocolHandler "file:///x:/temp/fragtest.htm#frag"

Mind the quotes!!!

rundll32 URL.dll, FileProtocolHandler file:///x:/temp/fragtest.htm#frag does work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows only, you could try

```
System.exec("cmd.exe start file:///C:/foo/bar.html#anchor")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [BrowserLauncher2](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/). It's a small and self-contained cross-platform library to open the default browser. It handles anchors perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Windows 7, the anchor is stripped. I think it's an OS issue, ProcessMonitor shows my call to Firefox without the anchor.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some investigation on this item [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187510/1084078) - note that opening `cmd` and typing `start file:///c:/temp/test.html#anchor` also doesn't work.

I think the only thing that actually works is to call a browser manually (or use a third-party tool that does this).

On Windows, you always have Internet Explorer, so you could call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe start iexplore " + myURL)` if you really don't want to find iexplore.exe yourself - but this doesn't always work either.