# How to open URL with anchors in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to add documentation to my project. By clicking on F1, I open the documentation in a certain place (for documentation I have 1 file(index.htm)). However, I can not open the URL with anchor. I have formed the correct URL, but .browse () open the document without anchor(at the beginning).

```
public void openHtmlDocument() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
     ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
     File file = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/documentation/index.htm"));
     URL url = new URL(file.toURI().toURL(), "#_Toc502051959");
     Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
 }
```

How can I fix this? The rest of other answers did not actual for me, because users use Windows or Linux.
Formed URI:

*file:/D:/app/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deployment545477ea955f6f3d/mainUI-1.2.14.0.war-7f1f239336b4e258/documentation/index.htm#_Toc502051959*

My browser URL after opening:

[image: *file:///D:/app/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deploymentcbce740f6f42d6cf/mainUI-1.2.14.0.war-6c39ba4477e29f99/documentation/index.htm*]

Comment: Instead of posting images of text (e.g. that URI) please post the text itself.

Comment: Thomas, Corrected a question according to your remark.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your browser's address bar? Did you check for any redirects etc.? And since you wrote "at the beginning" - do you mean it works once the browser is open?

Comment: Added the address in the browser. No, I meant that the document opens on line 1

Comment: It seems you are using JSF. Have you seen this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985761/anchor-jumpto-in-jsf)?

Comment: Those. I can try to change the page format to "xhtml" and add a JS function to the page? Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem, if suddenly someone faces the same problem:

```
    String menuNameNotBlanked = menuName == null ? "" : menuName.replace(" ","_");
    String formPathNotBlanked = formPath == null ? "" : formPath.replace(".xhtml","").replace("/","_");
    String helpPath = ((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getRealPath(HELP_FILE_PATH);

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    URL contextURL = new URL(request.getScheme(),request.getServerName(),request.getServerPort(),request.getContextPath());
    URL helpURL = new URL(contextURL.toString()+ "/" + HELP_FILE_PATH + AddLeadString(menuNameNotBlanked+formPathNotBlanked,"#"));
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('" + helpURL + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a pain. Desktop.browse is not working with anchors as discussed here:
[How to launch a file protocol URL with an anchor from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300509/how-to-launch-a-file-protocol-url-with-an-anchor-from-java)
The link gives possible workarounds for windows.

With Linux you may be able to open the url by executing this command:

```
Runtime.exec("open file:/D:/app/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deployment545477ea955f6f3d/mainUI-1.2.14.0.war-7f1f239336b4e258/documentation/index.htm#_Toc502051959");
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this doesn't resolved my problem